# Resize images for iPhone 5 6 and 6 plus

Tags: iphone, ios8, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a very simple question. I have designed a view in compactWidth|Regular Height and applied auto layout constraints on it.  What I want is My view should be stretched on the whole screen. I have buttons and a table of static height. But problem is when I run it on iPhone 6 it fits on the screen when I run on iPhone 5 it break the table height and shrinks it and when I run on 6 PLUS it leaves the space in table. I want the whole view to scale up and down for different iPhones.

Edit: I want to scale this view to iphone 5, 6 and 6 plus

Comment: I have uploaded the image please see this

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't use Auto-Layout or Size Classes, your only hope is to programmatically change the positions/size of each element individually in the viewDidAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews method of your LoginViewController. You would have to do it also on orientation change (if your app supports it).

It's a lot of work that can be easily be avoided by using Auto-Layout/Size Classes!

Comment: I am using autolayout and size classes already.. I have buttons and imageries and tables from top to bottom.. I want to resize all of them for different devices